# Repair Windows 10/Server 2012 R2 dual boot after W10 reinstall

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, windows-server-2012-r2

I had dual booting set up with Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012 R2. Windows 10 was installed on one drive, and then from within Windows 10 I ran setup for Windows Server 2012 R2 and installed it on a second drive. After this when booting I could select the OS to load, and shift + clicking Restart while in Windows would also give the option to reboot right to the other OS.

I did a clean Windows 10 reinstall, and after this dual booting is gone. I don't get the option when the computer starts up, and the Startup and Recovery options only list Windows 10. From within Windows 10 I can still see the Windows Server drive and everything is still there.

I looked up other similar questions and most answers were to do an automatic repair using the [Dual Boot Repair](http://www.boyans.net/DualBootRepair.html) tool so I tried that, but that did not fix it. Does this tool not working with Windows Server 2012 R2? I didn't see that OS listed explicitly on the tool site, but when running it it does seem to see it installed on the second drive. This is the confirmation I get when running auto repair.

[image]

What else can I do to repair dual booting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current implementation of "Automatic Repair" option implements one single task - it fixes the booting to latest Windows version in a dual/multi boot system (in this case Windows 10 is the latest Windows version).

You can use [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net) (when in Windows 10) to add a Windows Vista/7/8 loader for booting OS on Z: (Server 2012 R2).

Alternatively use Dual-boot Repair - "Repair BCD" option (when in Windows 10) and select "Z:\Windows" as source.

[image: Repair BCD on Z:]

Comment: Thank you Snayob! I was able to add a loader using Visual BCD Editor, point it to my Z drive, and now I can boot Windows Server 2012 R2 again.